# No Mocking on MongoRepository

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data, mockito

I have the following configuration

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackageClasses= {})
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes= {})
@ActiveProfiles("local")
```

I want to run a JUnit test without mocking the MongoRepository calls but it automatically mocks the MongoRepo calls and gives back null. Is their a way around it?

Comment: automatically mocks ? no way please explain with code

Comment: I am using MockMvc from Unit Test to hit my controller and the controller has a service layer that has this call to MongoDb repo.FindbyId(id), which returns a null and its returning a value when i run the actual application. this.mockMvc.perform(post("/").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(data1)).andExpect(status().isOk());

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should decide what kind of test you want to perform,

1. Unit test
   or
2. Integration test

If you are doing unit test , you should write separate test cases for each layer

**Controller layer**  - use mockmvc and mock service layer calls
**Service layer**  - Here you have two options, YOu can mock repository calls or you can use some in memory database(like Fongo) and put some data before testing and test it.

If you want to test all layers together and with real database then you should write Integration tests.

Comment: I want to test the whole suite of Microservices together i.e integration test. I am using Junit to do that and it is causing those mocking issues?

Comment: if you want to do integration test , why are you mocking

Comment: I am not mocking but when i try to make a call to my top level controller. It causes the db layer to be mocked automatically. Is it something to do with context configuration?